# Argument 'CustomersController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

i'm new to `angular js` and i'm following a tutorial and i'm getting this error `Argument 'CustomersController' is not a function, got undefined` my code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Filters</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="CustomersController">
    <h2>Customers</h2>
    Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name"/>
    <br /><br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>
            <th ng-click="sdoSort('city')">City</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('total')">Order Total</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:customerFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
            <td>{{ cust.name | uppercase }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.city | lowercase}}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.total | currency:'INR ' }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.joined | date }}</td>
        </tr>
        <span>Total customers : {{ customers.length }}</span>
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/controller/customerController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

now this is my CustomerController.js file

```
function CustomersController($scope){
$scope.sortBy = 'name';
$scope.reverse = false;

$scope.customers = [{joined:'2000-12-02',name:'John',city:'Chandler',total:'9.9959'},{joined:'1965-12-02',name:'Jon',city:'Chand',total:'9.959'},{joined:'1962-12-02',name:'On',city:'Chand',total:'9.9'},{joined:'1925-12-02',name:'Ron',city:'Chand',total:'10.23'}];
$scope.doSort = function(propName){
    $scope.sortBy = propName;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
};
```

}

i use google chrome's console so saw this error, i'm unable to find out what is wrong with my code as i'm following the instructor very well, i'm using angular js 1.3.11 version

Answer (score 1):

From Angular 1.3 onwards you could not use global functions. You should always create a module and then inject/create whatever component you wants inside that like controller, directive, etc.

**CODE**

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('CustomersController',function ($scope){
$scope.sortBy = 'name';
$scope.reverse = false;

$scope.customers = [{joined:'2000-12-02',name:'John',city:'Chandler',total:'9.9959'},{joined:'1965-12-02',name:'Jon',city:'Chand',total:'9.959'},{joined:'1962-12-02',name:'On',city:'Chand',total:'9.9'},{joined:'1925-12-02',name:'Ron',city:'Chand',total:'10.23'}];
$scope.doSort = function(propName){
    $scope.sortBy = propName;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
};
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

Thanks.

Comment: @runningmark you have couple of answers to mark..do correct one of it..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are overlooking a few of the basics for app setup. I'd suggest Follow this pattern demo'd here and I think you'll be up and running. Create an `app.js` file to keep things clean and bring it in like your `customerController.js` file

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

---

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app',
    [
    ]);
```

---

```
app.controller('CustomersController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.sortBy = 'name';
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.customers = [{joined:'2000-12-02',name:'John',city:'Chandler',total:'9.9959'},{joined:'1965-12-02',name:'Jon',city:'Chand',total:'9.959'},{joined:'1962-12-02',name:'On',city:'Chand',total:'9.9'},{joined:'1925-12-02',name:'Ron',city:'Chand',total:'10.23'}];
    $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
        $scope.sortBy = propName;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; 
    }
}]);
```